# Debian Apache2 Restart issue

Tags: bash, apache, unix, apache2, debian

The issue is my server had to be installed so I am trying to get the websites in www up and running. I have copied in my old contents of www but when I try to restart apache2 I get the following:

```
root@microsoft:/# service apache2 restart
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/microsoft.com:
Invalid command '../sites-available/microsoft.com', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

etc/apache2/sites-enabled/microsoft.com
inside the file: ../sites-available/microsoft.com

/etc/apache2/sites-available
inside the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@microsoft.com
ServerName microsoft.com
ServerAlias www.microsoft.com   

DocumentRoot /var/www/microsoft
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/microsoft>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Try again closing your <VirtualHost *:80> with a </VirtualHost> after </Directory>

Answer (score 0):

Try again closing your `<VirtualHost *:80>` with a `</VirtualHost>` after `</Directory>`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@microsoft.com
    ServerName microsoft.com
    ServerAlias www.microsoft.com   

    DocumentRoot /var/www/microsoft
    <Directory "/var/www/microsoft">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/microsoft>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: I had the virtual host line at the bottom, I forgot to paste it into my question. The question still stands, any idea what it might be? Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the code, What should the first directory be ?

Comment: root@microsoft:/# a2ensite microsoft:.com
ERROR: Site microsoft.com not properly enabled: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled                         /microsoft:.com is a real file, not touching it

Comment: When I got to my website online it shows the site folders in my www and if clicked they go to the website, but the domains themselves are not routed to the websites when used. Each domain points to the www folder.

Comment: Add a DirectiryIndex, like DirectoryIndex index.html. More info here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you symlinked it incorrectly and the sites-enabled version of the file is corrupt.

> "etc/apache2/sites-enabled/microsoft.com inside the file:
>   ../sites-available/microsoft.com"

You're showing the contents of the sites-available file, but the error message implies the content of the sites-enabled file is not a valid httpd configruation.

Follow the exiting pattern and read the error messages carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete your microsoft.com file in sites-enabled, rename microsoft.com to microsoft.com.**conf** in sites-available. Run a2ensite and restart apache2 service.